# Gaussian and Epanechnikov Kernel Regressions giving drastically different estimations

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, python, kernel-smoothing, nonparametric-regression

sorry if this is the wrong place to be asking this question.

I'm trying to implement kernel regression for a specific dataset I'm working with, but I'm noticing that the trendlines generated by my Gaussian and Epanechnikov kernels are significantly different and I don't believe the Epanechnikov implementation is accurate at all.  Gaussian implementation was shamelessly stolen, so I assume it's my adaptation to Epanechnikov that is the issue.  Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np

'''Class for Epanechnikov Kernel Regression'''
class EKR:
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, b):
        self.x = np.array(x)
        self.y = np.array(y)
        self.b = b
        
    '''Implement the Epanechnikov Kernel'''
    def epanechnikov_kernel(self, z):
        return (0.75*(1-np.power(z,2)))
    
    '''Calculate weights and return prediction'''
    def predict(self, X):
            kernels = np.array([self.epanechnikov_kernel((np.linalg.norm(xi-X))/self.b) for xi in self.x])
            weights = np.array([len(self.x) * (kernel/np.sum(kernels)) for kernel in kernels])
            return np.dot(weights.T, self.y)/len(self.x)

'''Class for Gaussian Kernel Regression'''
class GKR:
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, b):
        self.x = np.array(x)
        self.y = np.array(y)
        self.b = b
        
    '''Implement the Gaussian Kernel'''
    def gaussian_kernel(self, z):
        return (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-0.5*np.power(z,2))
    
    '''Calculate weights and return prediction'''
    def predict(self, X):
            kernels = np.array([self.gaussian_kernel((np.linalg.norm(xi-X))/self.b) for xi in self.x])
            weights = np.array([len(self.x) * (kernel/np.sum(kernels)) for kernel in kernels])
            return np.dot(weights.T, self.y)/len(self.x)
```

I understand Epanechnikov kernels have a bounded support of |u| <= 1 while Gaussians do not, so is it my failure to account for this that is leading to problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not surprising, Epanechnikov kernel is negative outside the bounds and kernels cannot return negative values (see example in Julia below). When you combine the negative and positive "density" values in kernel density estimation, you get rubbish results. Restricting the bounds in important in here, only Gaussian kernel is an exception as it is not bounded.

```
using Plots

epanechnikov(x) = 0.75 * (1 - x^2)
gaussian(x) = 1/sqrt(2π) * exp(-1/2 * x^2)

plot(epanechnikov, -2, 2, label = "Epanechnikov")
plot!(gaussian, -2, 2, label = "Gaussian")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Funnily enough, I was out for a walk when it occurred to me that this must be the case.  Setting the Epanechnikov function equal to zero when |z| > 1 fixed my issue; as you hinted, allowing the kernel to go negative was adding excess weight to the farthest points!